# How does the controller portion of the routing path get configured in .NET Web API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing .NET 4 console application which I want to start exposing a REST API.  I'm using the Microsoft self host Web API library to have it expose that API, but I'm having trouble understanding how the routing path gets developed.

Here is an example of a controller, which should expose some database objects my console application already handles:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    UserInformation[] users;

    public IEnumerable<UserInformation> GetAllUsers()
    {
         // snip.
    }

    public UserInformation GetUserById(int id)
    {
         // snip.
    }

}
```

And I'm exposing my API in Program.cs like so:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8800");
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config)) { // code }
```

Given the above code, I'd expect that I could get resources by making http requests like `http://localhost:8800/api/users` and `http://localhost:8800/api/users/1`, but those don't seem to work.  How does the controller part of the GET request get created?  It doesn't seem like users is the correct routing path for the API, but I'm not sure what goes there.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your controller is called `UserController` and not `UsersController`. Either rename your controller to `UsersController` or modify your request to go to `http://localhost:8800/api/user`.

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Should have been obvious!  It is all implicitly defined by the actual class name then?  That just feels so wrong.

Comment: Well it's not really that bad once you get the hang of it, which should be pretty quickly. :-)